# Is there a tidyverse approach to find paired rows in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tidy, pairing, rowwise

I have

```
df <-   data.frame(id = c(c(letters[1:4]), c(LETTERS[5:8])),
                     group = c(rep("same", length = 4), rep("opp", length = 4)),            
                     match = c("H", "G", "E", "F", "c", "d", "b", "a"))
```

where each id (row) is uniquely paired with one other id in the list. Hoping to find tidyverse solution to create an indicator column showing unique pairings using sequential numbers assigned to each pair. So the result would be the output of

```
df <-   data.frame(pair = c(1,2,3,4,3,4,2,1), id = c(c(letters[1:4]), c(LETTERS[5:8])),
                     group = c(rep("same", length = 4), rep("opp", length = 4)),            
                     match = c("H", "G", "E", "F", "c", "d", "b", "a"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of one to one relationship

df %>%
group_by(pair = pmin(id, match))%>%
mutate(pair = cur_group_id())

```
# A tibble: 8 × 4
# Groups:   pair [4]
  id    group match  pair
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 a     same  H         1
2 b     same  G         2
3 c     same  E         3
4 d     same  F         4
5 E     opp   c         3
6 F     opp   d         4
7 G     opp   b         2
8 H     opp   a         1
```

or

```
mutate(df, pair = match(pmin(id, match), id))
```

---

in Base R:

```
transform(df, pair = match(pmin(id,match), id))
  id group match pair
1  a  same     H    1
2  b  same     G    2
3  c  same     E    3
4  d  same     F    4
5  E   opp     c    3
6  F   opp     d    4
7  G   opp     b    2
8  H   opp     a    1
```

---

In case of one to many relationship:

```
df %>%
  group_by(pair= paste(pmin(id, match), pmax(id, match)))%>%
  mutate(pair =cur_group_id())

# A tibble: 8 × 4
# Groups:   pair [4]
  id    group match  pair
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 a     same  H         1
2 b     same  G         2
3 c     same  E         3
4 d     same  F         4
5 E     opp   c         3
6 F     opp   d         4
7 G     opp   b         2
8 H     opp   a         1
```

Comment: pmin was genius! Much better approach than my answer (+1)

Comment: @jpsmith just restricted to one to one relationship. I have editted it in case of a one to many relationship

Comment: Great solution and so simple. thanks for the opportunity to learn about pmin/pmax and cur_group_id

Answer (score 1):

There may be more elegant ways, but you can achieve your desired output in two `mutate` steps - the first one creates a temporary grouping variable (`tmp`) that is later removed with `select`, and the other uses `cur_group_id` to assign group numbers based on `tmp`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(tmp = ifelse(group %in% "same", paste0(id, match), paste0(match, id))) %>%
  mutate(pair = cur_group_id(), .by = tmp) %>% select(-tmp)
```

Output

```
  id group match pair
1  a  same     H    1
2  b  same     G    2
3  c  same     E    3
4  d  same     F    4
5  E   opp     c    3
6  F   opp     d    4
7  G   opp     b    2
8  H   opp     a    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  group_by(pair = map2_chr(id, match, ~ str_flatten(sort(c(.x, .y))))) |>
  mutate(pair = cur_group_id()) |>
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `factor`

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(pair = factor(paste(sort(c(id, match)), collapse = "")), 
         pair = as.numeric(pair)) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  id    group match  pair
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 a     same  H         1
2 b     same  G         2
3 c     same  E         3
4 d     same  F         4
5 E     opp   c         3
6 F     opp   d         4
7 G     opp   b         2
8 H     opp   a         1
```